# How to create global object Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, instagram-api

I'm using *Laravel 5.6* and [*Instagram API library*](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API).

To work with this Instagram API I need to create object `$ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram()`. And then for getting any user's information I must use `$ig->login('username', 'password')` every time.

So I don't want to use this function all the time. The first I want to create a global variable which will contain `$ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram()`. However, I don't know how to correctly do it.

- I tried to use [*singleton*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers#the-register-method):

  ```
  $this->app->singleton(Instagram::class, function ($app) {
      Instagram::$allowDangerousWebUsageAtMyOwnRisk = true; // As wiki says
      return new Instagram();
  });
  ```

  When I called `$ig->login('name', 'pass')` in any method all user profile's information changed in this object, but then if I call `dd($ig = app(Instagram::class))` in another Controller method I see that previous data did not save. **"WTF?" - I said**.

  > Someone tells me that *singleton* just promise me that there won't be created the same object, but it does not save any changes.
- I tried  to use [*sessions*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#storing-datahttps://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#storing-data):

  However, when I tried to set variable with object as value anything did not happen.

  ```
  $ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram();
  session(['ig' => $ig]);
  ```

  I think it's because of I tried to put a large object. ***And from the other hand it's not secure method!***

---

Just let me know:

### How can I create an object which I could use in every method with saving change for the next actions?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right storage, [check this](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/wiki#constructor).

Comment: There says: *If you want to use a mySQL storage...*. **IF** But, I don't want to use mysql :D

Comment: How did you set up the singleton? A singleton should work for this so I wonder if it wasn't registered correctly.

Comment: @jfadich, updated question. I can't understand why object's properties did not changed..?

Comment: That's what I thought. You want to call `$ig->login('name', 'pass')` inside the singleton register call. The result of the function is what is passed to functions, any changes you make after it is injected are not propagated back up into the container.

Comment: @jfadich, so what I need to do? I want to call singleton and I expect that it returns `$ig` object.. Can you explain in more details or just answer :D?

Answer (score 3):

> When I called $ig->login('name', 'pass') in any method all user profile's information changed in this object, but then if I call dd($ig = app(Instagram::class)) in another Controller method I see that previous data did not save.

That is the correct behavior. When a new request is sent to Laravel, a new instance of the `Instagram` is created. I'm not sure if you understand the meaning of a singleton but in terms of Laravel, there is one instance per HTTP request.

Since the Instagram API you're using does not contain functionality to relogin, I created a class (that would be place in the `app/Classes` folder).

```
<?php
namespace App\Classes;

use InstagramAPI\Instagram;
use InstagramAPI\Response\LoginResponse;

class CustomInstagram extends Instagram {
    public function relogin(LoginResponse $response) {
        $appRefreshInterval = 1800;

        $this->_updateLoginState($response);
        $this->_sendLoginFlow(true, $appRefreshInterval);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Change the singleton instance so it uses the `App\Classes\CustomInstagram` class.

```
$this->app->singleton(Instagram::class, function ($app) {
    Instagram::$allowDangerousWebUsageAtMyOwnRisk = true; // As wiki says
    return new App\Classes\CustomInstagram();
});
```

In order to use the `Instagram` object with an authenticated user, the login information will need to be persisted some how. This would be placed where the login is occurring.

```
try {
    $response = app(Instagram::class)->login($username, $password);

    if ($response->isTwoFactorRequired()) {
        // Need to handle if 2fa is needed (we're not completely logged in yet)
    }

    // Can use session to persist \InstagramAPI\Response\LoginResponse but I'd recommend the database.
    session(['igLoginResponse' => serialize($response)]);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Login failed
}
```

Then create a middleware to relogin the user to Instagram (if the login response exists). You need to register this as [described here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#registering-middleware). Then, the Instagram singleton can be used in your controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use InstagramAPI\Instagram;

class InstagramLogin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $responseSerialized = session('igLoginResponse');

        if (!is_null($responseSerialized)) {
            $ig = app(Instagram::class);

            $response = unserialize($responseSerialized);

            $ig->relogin($response);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try to do it in a few days, thanks! If everything will be OK i choose your answer as best :D